# How to get the output of node.js file in terminal Mac?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to test [this](https://github.com/Belema/custom-hash)

When I test this code online in [runkit.com](https://npm.runkit.com/)

```javascript
*var hash = require('custom-hash');
hash.configure({ charSet: [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'K', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',], maxLength: 26 });
    
hash.digest('Hello World!');
```

I get this result:

```
175GKG3K6UZ6GAEE64BFKUN0MR
```

I just installed the custom-hash package in Mac and made the file `test.js` exactly with the code working online and type in terminal `node test.js` and I get no output

Can you help please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your final line with something like this:

```
let result = hash.digest('Hello World!');
console.log('this is the result: ' + result)
```

Whatever npm.runkit is doing for output you will need to do manually in a node script. `console.log` is a fine way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks clay it worked!

After I have achieved the second step, get the hash of a file instead of a string, by modifying the code like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let result = hash.digest(fs.readFileSync('/users/Test.PDF'));
```

And now, how can I compile it now to be an executable desktop app?

Thanks in advance?